# PHP - sort hash array by key length

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key

I've found a few answers to sorting by value, but not key.

What I'd like to do is a reverse sort, so with:

```
    $nametocode['reallylongname']='12';
    $nametocode['shortname']='10';
    $nametocode['mediumname']='11';
```

I'd like them to be in this order

1. reallylongname
2. mediumname
3. shortname

mediumname shortname

Many thanks

Answer (score 31):

Another solution using [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort):

```
$keys = array_map('strlen', array_keys($arr));
array_multisort($keys, SORT_DESC, $arr);
```

Here `$keys` is an array of the lengths of the keys of `$arr`. That array is sorted in descending order and then used to sort the values of `$arr` using `array_multisort`.

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a performance advantage to this over `uksort()`?

Comment: @thetaiko: No, I don’t think so. But you’ll have to profile to be sure. The main difference is that there is no custom comparison function required as the key values are compared to distinguish the order.

Comment: I like this one because it's easy to turn it into one line

Answer (score 11):

Based on @thetaiko answer, with a simpler callback :

```
function sortByLengthReverse($a, $b){
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
}

uksort($nametocode, "sortByLengthReverse");
```

---

#### Resources :

- [php.net - `uksort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)
- [php.net - Sorting arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)
- [php.net - `strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Answer (score 9):

You can use a user defined key sort function as a callback for `uksort`:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if (strlen($a) == strlen($b))
        return 0;
    if (strlen($a) > strlen($b))
        return 1;
    return -1;
}

uksort($nametocode, "cmp");

foreach ($nametocode as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Quick note - to reverse the sort simply switch "1" and "-1".

Answer (score 5):

Behold my powerful inline methodologies. Preserve global space for the generations to come!

```
uksort($data, create_function('$a,$b', 'return strlen($a) < strlen($b);'));
```

Comment: Nice, but doesn't work well. Not truly ASC or DESC.

Comment: @KhomNazid - you made the same comment above, but this answer, like mine, works perfectly.  Maybe you can elaborate or provide an example so we can understand why you think these answers aren't sorting the way you expect?

Answer (score 3):

I have benchmarked some of sorting algorithms since performance is important for my project - here's what I've found (averaged result ran 1000x, sorted field had cca 300 elements with key size 3-50 chars):

- 2.01 sec ... uksort with anonymous create_function (by cojam)
- 0.28 sec ... array_multisort (by Gumbo)
- 2.69 sec ... uksort with non-anonymous function (by Colin Herbert) - surprise for me,
- 0.15 sec ... simple foreach + arsort

Sometime simple foreach still wins. 
Using dynamic PHP features has some performance penalty, obviously.

Comment: And how does this answer the actual question? This should've been a comment, not an answer, unless you'd provide the code you tested it with.

Comment: @vanowm Code is there on this page - look up answer by cojam, Gumbo, Colin Herbert. Their code was benchmarked. And it would be really hard to put benchmarking results into a single comment while added informative value might be significant for some projects, as it was for mine.

Comment: I'm just saying, that even though your "answer" contains good information, it doesn't actually answer the question...I don't see anyone posted "simple foreach + arsort" code examples, so since it seems to have best performance, perhaps if you'd post it, it will make it a true answer... ;)

Answer (score 3):

In PHP7+ you can use `uksort()` with spaceship operator and anonymous function like this:

```
uksort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b) <=> strlen($a);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Array is not sorted properly.

Answer (score 2):

One limitation while sorting the keys on the basis of length is that: equal length keys are not re-ordered. Say we need to order the keys by length in `descending` order.

```
$arr = array(
    "foo 0" => "apple",
    "foo 1" => "ball",
    "foo 2 foo 0 foo 0" => "cat",
    "foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 0" => "dog",
    "foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 1" => "elephant",
    "foo 2 foo 1 foo 0" => "fish",
    "foo 2 foo 1 foo 1" => "giraffe"
);

debug($arr, "before sort");
$arrBad = $arr;
sortKeysDescBAD($arrBad);
debug($arrBad, "after BAD sort");
sortKeysDescGOOD($arr);
debug($arr, "after GOOD sort 2");

function sortKeysDescBAD(&$arrNew) {
    $arrKeysLength = array_map('strlen', array_keys($arrNew));
    array_multisort($arrKeysLength, SORT_DESC, $arrNew);
    //return max($arrKeysLength);
}

function sortKeysDescGOOD(&$arrNew) {
    uksort($arrNew, function($a, $b) {
        $lenA = strlen($a); $lenB = strlen($b);
        if($lenA == $lenB) {
            // If equal length, sort again by descending
            $arrOrig = array($a, $b);
            $arrSort = $arrOrig;
            rsort($arrSort);
            if($arrOrig[0] !== $arrSort[0]) return 1;
        } else {
            // If not equal length, simple
            return $lenB - $lenA;
        }
    });
}

function debug($arr, $title = "") {
    if($title !== "") echo "<br/><strong>{$title}</strong><br/>";
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr); echo "</pre><hr/>";
}
```

**Output will be:**

```
before sort
Array
(
    [foo 0] => apple
    [foo 1] => ball
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 0] => cat
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 0] => dog
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 1] => elephant
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 0] => fish
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 1] => giraffe
)

after BAD sort
Array
(
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 0] => dog
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 1] => elephant
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 0] => cat
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 0] => fish
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 1] => giraffe
    [foo 0] => apple
    [foo 1] => ball
)

after GOOD sort
Array
(
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 1] => elephant
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 0] => dog
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 1] => giraffe
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 0] => fish
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 0] => cat
    [foo 1] => ball
    [foo 0] => apple
)
```

Notice the order of `elephant` and `dog` for example (or others) in two sorting methods. The second method looks better. There may be easier ways to solve this but hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 2):

To absolutely use ***uksort*** you can do like this:

```
$nametocode['reallylongname']='12';
$nametocode['name']='17';
$nametocode['shortname']='10';
$nametocode['mediumname']='11';

uksort($nametocode, function($a, $b) {
   return strlen($a) - strlen($b);
});

array_reverse($nametocode, true);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
   [reallylongname] => 12
   [mediumname] => 11
   [shortname] => 10
   [name] => 17
)
```

I have tested this code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [uksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php).

Answer (score 0):

The code below sorts the PHP hash array by string length of the key, then by the case-sensitive key itself, both in ascending order, using a lambda function:

```
uksort($yourArray, function ($a, $b) { 
   return (strlen($a) == strlen($b) ? strcmp($a, $b) : strlen($a) - strlen($b));
});
```

This code does the same in reverse order:

```
uksort($yourArray, function ($b, $a) { 
   return (strlen($a) == strlen($b) ? strcmp($a, $b) : strlen($a) - strlen($b));
});
```

Comment: And how does one call it??

Comment: @KhomNazid it's a complete code, there is nothing to "call". It modifies`$yourArray`.

Answer (score -1):

A simple problem requires a simple solution ;-)

```
arsort($nametocode, SORT_NUMERIC);
$result = array_keys($nametocode);
```