# PHP: how to sort by key length then by key asc?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955628/134824) which works for sorting by key length, but now I need to sort by key asc without ruining the initial sort.

Input example:

```
$arr = ['a' => 'A', 'ddd' => 'D', 'ccc' => 'C', 'bb' => 'B'];
```

Output example:

```
$arr = ['ccc' => 'C', 'ddd' => 'D', 'bb' => 'B', 'a' => 'A'];
```

---

Initial array:

```
a   => A
ddd => D
ccc => C
bb  => B
```

Sort by key length will sort them by longest first (while still preserving longest must be first), like this:

```
ddd => D
ccc => C
bb  => B
a   => A
```

Then, sort by key asc will change it to be like this:

```
ccc => C
ddd => D
bb  => B
a   => A
```

Needless to say, key/value pair should be maintained.

How to do that in PHP?

Comment: how, `Then, sort by key asc will change it to be like this: ` after output come? Any logic? is it by both? length and character?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You managed to pick the answer that is least suitable for what you want. Go with `uksort`, and write your own little comparison function, that compares to keys according to _both_ of your criteria.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I know I sound like newbie asking others to solve my problem, but I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uksort($array, function($key1, $key2) {
    $lengthMatch = strlen($key1) <=> strlen($key2);
    if ($lengthMatch) {
        return $lengthMatch;
    }
    return $key1 <=> $key2;
});
```

Explanation:

`uksort()` sorts an array by key, using a function in the second argument to determine the sort order.

The function first compares the key lengths. The `<=>` operator will return `-1` or `1` depending on whether the first or second value is greater, or zero if they are the same. The sort algorithm expects these values for sorting.

The `if()` will return the result of the length check if they're not the same lenth. If they are the same length, then we do a check on the actual value of the keys and return the result of that check instead.

Comment: [Order of output doesn't match](https://3v4l.org/dhaHE) and also it's format.

Comment: This `strlen($key1) <=> $strlen($key2);` needs to be `strlen($key2) <=> $strlen($key1);`

Comment: Perfect! Just fix this typo `$strlen($key2);`by removing the $

Comment: @evilReiko oops. fixed. Thanks for that :-)