# Sort an array in descending order by key length (key length in value) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

My question is an extension/variation on [this already well-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955536/php-sort-hash-array-by-key-length):

There is an array with binary-looking keys:

```
    codeWords = [
        '000111' => [6, 1, 0, 't'],
        '1110' => [4, 6, 0, 't'],
        '10011' => [5, 8, 0, 't'],
        '001000' => [6, 12, 0, 't'],
        '00110101' => [8, 0, 0, 't'],
        '010' => [3, 1, 1, 't'],
        '10' => [2, 3, 1, 't'],
        '011' => [3, 4, 1, 't'],
        '0010' => [4, 6, 1, 't'],
        '00011' => [5, 7, 1, 't'],
        '000101' => [6, 8, 1, 't'],
    ];
```

I need this array ordered like this:

```
    $codeWords = [
        '00110101' => [8, 0, 0, 't'],
        '001000' => [6, 12, 0, 't'],
        '000111' => [6, 1, 0, 't'],
        '000101' => [6, 8, 1, 't'],
        '10011' => [5, 8, 0, 't'],
        '00011' => [5, 7, 1, 't'],
        '1110' => [4, 6, 0, 't'],
        '0010' => [4, 6, 1, 't'],
        '011' => [3, 4, 1, 't'],
        '010' => [3, 1, 1, 't'],
        '10' => [2, 3, 1, 't'],
    ];
```

This solution is working fine:

```
    uksort($codeWords, function($a, $b) {
        return strlen($a) < strlen($b);
    });
```

but...

...key length is already stored in `value[0]`. Therefore, `strlen()` does not have to be used in the comparison function.

I have tried to adapt some of the solutions given in the linked question accordingly with using `value[0]`- but do not come to the desired result.

Can someone get me on the right track?

Comment: uksort uses the keys, but you want to sort by `value[0]` ?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly should the end result be? Try to form your question/s like this: Given this world... (you already did that. so OK), When I do this...(explain what do you do, also done. OK), I expect this to happen...(explain what do you expect to happen, this is missing).

Comment: @lewis4u I thought the headline would describe it well enough

Comment: Make the final output array from that at the beginning.... what should it look like? The longest key should be at the top and the shortest key at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [uksort](https://www.php.net/uksort) function specifically uses array keys, and thus your code `return $a[0] < $b[0];` compares only first symbols of your `0010101` keys.

You need [uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

```
    uasort($codeWords, function($a, $b) {
        return $b[0] - $a[0];
    });
```

Comment: I had tried this before: then the keys are replaced by numerical indices

Comment: Right, my bad, it's [uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) then. Fixed.

Comment: Also I've put links to the English version of docs.