# Change parts of a string with values from an array, but only when the whole value can be found

Tags: php, str-replace

I have to replace strings of multiple country names to their translations in another language. So I created an array of countries, where the keys are the countries in English and the values are the countries in the destination language...

So, let me first put a relevant extract of the array I used:

```
$countries = array(
    //...
    'Canada' => 'Καναδάς',
    //...
    'France' => 'Γαλλία',
    //...
    'Germany' => 'Γερμανία',
    //...
    'Korea' => 'Κορέα',
    //...
    'South Korea' => 'Νότια Κορέα',
    //...
    'United States' => 'Ηνωμένες Πολιτείες',
    //...
    'West Germany' => 'Δυτική Γερμανία',
    //...
);
```

And the code I used is this:

```
$tmp[] = str_replace(array_keys($countries), $countries, $api->getCountry());
```

And below are two (special case) examples that are giving me a hard time figuring out how to deal with them...

```
West Germany • France
United States • Canada • South Korea
```

So the above two examples are replaced like this:

```
West Γερμανία • Γαλλία
Ηνωμένες Πολιτείες • Καναδάς • South Κορέα
```

I think it's very obvious what's happening here... The key Germany is found before the key West Germany, so str_replace replaces the Germany part with the translated name of it, and so West remains untranslated... The same happens with Korea, which (alphabetically) happens to be before South Korea...

Moving West Germany and South Korea above Germany and Korea fixes the problem, but this is not the proper way to deal with this I suppose, as it will happen to East Germany, and generally, any other country that has a two-word, etc...

What's the correct way to deal with this in your opinion? TIA

Comment: Does `$api->getCountry()` return only 1 country name or multiple country names separated by  • like in your example?

Comment: Like in my example, multiple countries separated by a &middot;

Comment: Then `explode` the resulting string by  •, loop it and then match it exactly to the `key` of your translation array.

Comment: I was looking for a more clever/short way than exploding/matching/imploding...

Comment: Sort the original translation array by length of the `key`? This way composite country names will always be above the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit of a cheat but if you're going to use array_keys rather than a loop, you should just presort the countries array by length.

```
$keys = array_map('strlen', array_keys($countries));
array_multisort($keys, SORT_DESC, $countries);
$tmp[] = str_replace(array_keys($countries), $countries, $api->getCountry());
```

Here's a little example you can test at: https://www.tehplayground.com/uARSRel47jYICSIA

```
$countries = array(
  'Canada' => 'Καναδάς',
  'France' => 'Γαλλία',
  'Germany' => 'Γερμανία',
  'Korea' => 'Κορέα',
  'South Korea' => 'Νότια Κορέα',
  'United States' => 'Ηνωμένες Πολιτείες',
  'West Germany' => 'Δυτική Γερμανία'
);

$keys = array_map('strlen', array_keys($countries));
array_multisort($keys, SORT_DESC, $countries);

echo str_replace(array_keys($countries), $countries, "West Germany"). "\n";
echo str_replace(array_keys($countries), $countries, "France") . "\n";
echo str_replace(array_keys($countries), $countries, "United States") . "\n";
echo str_replace(array_keys($countries), $countries, "Canada") . "\n";
echo str_replace(array_keys($countries), $countries, "South Korea") . "\n";
```

Output:

```
Δυτική Γερμανία
Γαλλία
Ηνωμένες Πολιτείες
Καναδάς
Νότια Κορέα
```

**Update**

As it turns out `uksort` takes care of this in one line:

```
uksort($countries,function($a, $b) { return strlen($b) > strlen($a);});
```

Comment: This works great. To be 100% fair, @Andrea Olivato suggested the same thing, but you also provided a working piece of code, so _you win_!

I only have a remark on your answer... Some keys have Unicode characters, so `strlen` produces wrong results for those keys... I used `mb_strlen` instead, and now it works great!

Those keys are

```'Åland Islands'
"Côte d'Ivoire"
'Réunion'
'Saint Barthélemy'```

Comment: Credit due to @AndreaOlivato - honestly I didn't see that comment. If you mark as the answer, I wish I could split the award :)

Comment: And I also have one question, as I've not used `array_multisort` much in the past, so I'm not quite sure how your suggestion works... I understand that `$keys` contains an array of the lengths of each key of the `$countries` array. But then, how does this end up sorting the actual `$countries` keys the way I need? Does it use this array

```Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 7
//...
    [256] => 5
    [257] => 10
    [258] => 5
    [259] => 6
    [260] => 8
)```

in an associative way like 0 - Afghanistan, 1 - Åland Islands etc?

Comment: array_multisort can be used in different ways. Here it's being used to take $keys,  sort Z-A, then apply as a $dimension to resort $countries . If you look at the link now, you'll see how it gets transformed - https://www.tehplayground.com/lMpJAS5IfCIc7TIu

Comment: I mean, just for testing I ran `arsort($keys, SORT_NUMERIC);` and `$keys` array ended up like this 

```Array
(
    [215] => 44
    [247] => 36
    [101] => 33
    [61] => 32
    [27] => 32
    [198] => 32
    [76] => 30
    //...
    [126] => 4
    [78] => 4
    [57] => 4
    [166] => 4
    [45] => 4
    [109] => 4
    [140] => 4
)```

So, does this mean that what `array_multisort(array_map('mb_strlen', array_keys($countries)), SORT_DESC, $countries);` does behind the curtains, is it sorts `$countries` in this order of its keys: 215, 247, 101, 61, 27, 198... etc?

Comment: Look at that link I just sent. It might help explain

Comment: So sorting doesn't occur in an associative way/manner... It simply sorts the values in a reverse numerical order... Then, how does `array_multisort` end up sorting the initial `$countries` array? Does it just search for any key with length of 44 chars to put in 0 position, or specifically the value whose $key was originally the 215th one? This is what I don't quite understand!

Comment: It's a mystery to me too! :) I just tested with another array `$test = [30,29,26,25,22,20,16];` instead of keys, thinking it needed just a sort order as reference and it didn't work. Somehow (not associative) the sorted $keys are associated to $countries in multisort. I'm not clear how though

Comment: I guess I'll have to make do with the fast that it works, however that is happening! Hehehe! Thanks a lot once again! :D

Comment: I added an update - we can do the same thing with `uksort` which actually makes alot more sense

Comment: Yesterday, while I was searching for an explanation of how `array_multishort` actually makes this work, I came across the link below, where a guy benchmarked each solution... It turns out `array_multisort` is very effective - marginally a little more time-consuming than a traditional `foreach` loop, with `uksort` being by far the more time-consuming solution... So I think I'll stick to your original suggestion! ;) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994495/15576971

Comment: How bout that! Thanks for sharing